# How to find all character pairs within a string

Tags: java, string, char

For the project I have in class, I have to count the diad.
For example, if the input is this line:

```
ab ab.
```

there will be 6 diads in total.
Which are:

```
"ab", "b ", " a", "ab", "b." and ".\n"
```

How can I scan the input char by char and find all the diads?
What I currently have is:

```
int i=0;
while(input.hasNext()){
    char c = input.next().charAt(i);
    i++;
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

However, this only prints out one character from the string at a time.  Can anyone help me in modifying my code?

Comment: What language are you using? C++? Also regex is not required to solve this problem. It's easily solvable without.

Comment: You should read the whole line into a String object and then find all the diads using String manipulation functions.

Comment: then what should I put in the condition of my while loop

Comment: I don't see any regex in his question. And you!? @AeroX

Comment: @Pier-AlexandreBouchard Check the Question edit history

Comment: Ok, I didn't see the edited tags. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate on your caracters once the line is fully read instead of using a `Scanner`, with something like this:

```
String input = "ab ab.\n";

for(int i = 0; i < input.length() - 1; i++){
   String c = "" + input.charAt(i) + input.charAt(i + 1);
   System.out.println(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right you probably want to treat this as pseudo-code because I don't program in Java, but the logic is the same regardless of the language.

You want to save what the previous char read was in a separate variable so that you can join it to the currently read char to turn it into a diad.

We do nothing on the first loop so that we have 2 chars to begin with. That's what the `if (p == '\0') continue;` is for.

```
int i = 0;
char p, c = '\0';
while (input.hasNext())
{
    p = c;
    c = input.next().charAt(i++);
    if (p == '\0') continue; // Check that p is not null (so that we have 2 chars)

    System.out.println("{0}{1}", p, c);
}
```